# POST request with form data

Tags: python, session, post, request, python-requests

I'm trying to simulate a request
that has various headers and bracketed form data.

Form Data:

```
{"username": "MY_USERNAME", "pass": "MY_PASS", "AUTO": "true"}
```

That is the form data shown in the console of Chrome
So I tried putting it together with Python's `requests` library:

```
import requests
reqUrl = 'http://website.com/login'
postHeaders = {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Length': '68',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'Host': 'website.com',
    'Origin': 'http://www.website.com',
    'Referer': 'http://www.website.com/',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/37.0.2062.120 Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36'
}

payload = {"username": "MY_USERNAME",
    "pass": "MY_PASS",
    "AUTO": "true"
}

session = requests.Session()
response = session.post(reqUrl, data=payload, headers=postHeaders)
```

I'm receiving a response but it shows:

```
{"status":"failure","error":"Invalid request data"}
```

Am I going about implementing the form data wrong? I was also thinking it could have to do with modifying the `Content-Length`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are setting a content length, overriding anything `requests` might set. You are setting too many headers, leave most of those to the library instead:

```
postHeaders = {
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Origin': 'http://www.website.com',
    'Referer': 'http://www.website.com/',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/37.0.2062.120 Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36'
}
```

is plenty. All the others will be generated for you.

However, from your description of the form data, it looks like you are posting JSON instead. In that case, use the `json` keyword argument instead of `data`, which will encode your payload to JSON and set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`:

```
response = session.post(reqUrl, json=payload, headers=postHeaders)
```

Comment: Got too far ahead of myself. I altered to the headers posted and still am receiving the same error.

Comment: @ZacharyWeeden: then triple-check what Chrome is actually posting, if there are other headers in there that perhaps signing data, etc. And are you sure it is not sending JSON, by the way?

Comment: @ZacharyWeeden: also, what is the HTTP status code?

Comment: @ZacharyWeeden: at any rate, there are no more obvious `requests` or Python errors in your code. Exactly what a website accepts is entirely up to the website.

Comment: It's returning 200. I think it is JSON. I overlooked the type in network tab. It shows application/json. data=json.dump(payload)

Comment: I used json.dump(payload) for the data in the request and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: @ZacharyWeeden: in that case, use `json=payload` and not only will `requests` encode the data to JSON for you, but the right header will be set too.